# Find the expression of $\frac{1}{Dx^2-Dy^2} \sin (x-y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Find the expression of $\frac{1}{Dx^2-Dy^2} \sin (x-y)$

May I ask if anybody could, please, tell me how to do this? I am not getting anything on this.

$$
\frac{1}{Dx^2-Dy^2} \sin (x-y)
 = \frac{1}{D(x^2-y^2)} \sin (x-y)
 = \int \frac{\sin (x-y)}{x^2-y^2} 
$$

Not sure which one to tag. So including differential and partial differential tags

I do not know what details I need to add. I am preparing for a competitive exam and the question is asked in previous year model paper. I just posted it as it is. After seeing the explanation I got to see it belongs to partial differential equations, but I thought it is from differential equations. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Just for clarity, I assume that $Dx^2 - Dy^2$ is supposed to mean ${\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)}^2 - {\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)}^2$, right?

Comment: operator method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result of that expression actually gives a particular solution to the PDE $D_x^2u-D_y^2u=u_{xx}-u_{yy}=\sin(x-y).$ This is called an operator method to find particular solutions.

$u_p= \frac{1}{Dx^2-Dy^2} \sin (x-y)=\frac{1}{-1-1}\sin (x-y)=-\frac{1}{2}\sin(x-y),$

where we have used $D_x^2=-1$ and $D_y^2=-1$ coming from the general formula $$\frac{1}{P(Dx^2, Dy^2)} \sin (ax+by)=\frac{1}{P(-a^2, -b^2)} \sin (ax+by)$$ and in your case the partial differential operator $P$ is $P(Dx^2, Dy^2)=Dx^2-Dy^2$.

Edit: I have made a mistake because the above formula does not work as @achille hui commented because $P(-a^2, -b^2)=0$. To resolve this after factorizing the operator we use the formula $$\frac{1}{P(D_x, D_y)}e^{ax+by}=\frac{1}{P(a, b)}e^{ax+by}$$
provided that $P(a, b)\neq 0$. 
$$u_p= \frac{1}{Dx^2-Dy^2} \sin (x-y)=\frac{1}{Dx^2-Dy^2} \text{Im} e^{i(x-y)}=\frac{1}{(D_x+D_y)(D_x-D_y)} \text{Im} e^{i(x-y)}$$

$$=\frac{1}{(D_x+D_y)(D_x-D_y)} \text{Im} e^{i(x-y)}=\frac{1}{(D_x+D_y)} \text{Im}\frac{e^{i(x-y)}}{2i}=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\text{Im} \frac{e^{i(x-y)}}{2i}=-\frac{1}{4}(x+y)\cos(x-y).$$

For the last two steps first we have to calculate 
$\frac{1}{bD_x-aD_y} e^{ax+by}$. Notice that in this case when $D_x=a$ and $D_y=b$, the denominator is zero. To do so,
I have used this formula $$\frac{1}{bD_x-aD_y} e^{ax+by}=\frac{ay-bx}{2ab}e^{ax+by}.\qquad (1) $$

Applying (1) to $\frac{1}{D_x+D_y} e^{ix-iy}$ with $a=i$ and $b=-i$ we get 
$$\frac{1}{D_x+D_y} e^{ix-iy}=\frac{(-iy-ix)}{2(i)(-i)}e^{ix-iy}=-\frac{i}{2}(x+y)e^{ix-iy}=-\frac{i}{2}(x+y)e^{i(x-y)}.$$
Thus using this and Euler's formula $e^{it}=\cos t+i\sin t$ and taking the imaginary part of the resulting expression with $t=x-y$ we find  $-\frac{1}{4}(x+y)\cos(x-y).$
Note: Of course for some operators it may be better to use another way to find a particular solutions. I have used this because your question about operator method.

Comment: @achille hui: you are completely right I should have been more careful careful because that formula requires $P(-a^2, -b^2)\neq 0$. I will fix it. Thanks

Comment: can you pls tell me how did u get last 2 steps - $\frac{1}{D_x+D_y} Im  \frac{e^{i(x-y)}}{2i} = \frac{1}{2}(x+y)  Im  \frac{e^{i(x-y)}}{2i}$. I am a beginner in this area. Pls elaborate

Comment: @anirudh: I added some calculatios to clarify the last steps.

Comment: thank you. Can you pls suggest me some book on partial differential equations. I am finding it difficult to understand. Some simple book which explains me concept in easy way (2) some book which contains lot of problems to practice.

Comment: @anirudh b: There many PDEs books for undergraduate and graduate levels as well as online notes in the net. Among them I can list the following books which are undergraduate level. Rene Dennemeyer (Introduction to PDEs and BVPs), Ian Sneddon (Elements of PDEs), Stanley J. Farlow (PDEs for scientists and engineers), Tyn Myint-U Lokenath( Linear PDEs for scientists and engineers), E. C. Zahmanoglu, Dale W. Thoe(Introduction to PDEs with applications), Robert McOwen (PDEs: Methods and Applications)

Answer (score 4):

This answer assumes that $\frac{1}{Dx^2 - Dy^2}$ is meant to represent the inverse of the differential operator
$$
{\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)}^2 - {\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)}^2 = \partial_x^2 - \partial_y^2\, .
$$

We are trying to find a function $f(x,y)$ such that
$$
\left(\partial_x^2 - \partial_y^2\right)f(x,y) \;=\; \sin(x - y)\, .
$$

Define new variables $u = x - y$ and $v = x+y$. Then
$$
\partial_x^2 - \partial_y^2 \;=\; \left(\partial_x - \partial_y\right)\left(\partial_x + \partial_y\right)\;=\; 4\,  \partial_u \partial_v\, 
$$
and our problem simplifies to finding a function $g(u, v)$ such that
$$
4\, \partial_u \partial_v\, g(u, v) \;=\; \sin u\, .
$$

Either by inspection or by indefinitely integrating both sides once each with respect to both $u$ and $v$, we see that the general solution to this is
$$
g(u, v) \;=\; -\frac{v}{4}\, \cos u \;+\; A(u) \;+\; B(v)\, ,
$$
where $A(u)$ and $B(v)$ are *entirely arbitrary* functions of $u$ and $v$, respectively. Substituting in our original change of variables for $u$ and $v$, we then find that the (non-unique) answer to the original problem is
$$
f(x, y) \;=\; -\frac{x+y}{4} \cos(x - y) \;+\; A(x-y) \;+\; B(x+y)\, .
$$